# Permission Denied when creating myapp in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

As the first time with linux and ruby on rails, I am following this guide, `https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10` everthing in the steps works fine except the final step when I tried to execute this command.

> rails new myapp -d mysql

after hitting `enter` I got this message.

```
/home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /myapp (Errno::EACCES)
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:253:in `fu_mkdir'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:227:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:225:in `reverse_each'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:225:in `block in mkdir_p'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `each'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/fileutils.rb:211:in `mkdir_p'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:50:in `block in invoke!'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:116:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:49:in `invoke!'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:94:in `action'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:14:in `empty_directory'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:153:in `create_root'
        from (eval):1:in `create_root'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/exe/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/rails:22:in `load'
        from /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

What is the problem?, can you suggest a solution?

Comment: can you run `mkdir test-dir`?

Comment: I says `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test-dir’: Permission denied`

Comment: So, the user you are logged in as does not have write permission where you are running this command. Are you running it at `~` (home)?

Comment: What does `pwd` output?

Comment: Thank @Jagdeep I just move to `home/fil`

Comment: you can do it if you are administrator user, `runas /noprofile /user:Administrator cmd` then run the `rails new` command